# Is there an application for boosting the bass levels of all system audio?

Tags: itunes, software-recommendation, music

Is there any application to boost the bass levels in all audio output?

I started searching for it because I have a HTC Wildfire phone and loaded Cyanogenmod onto it. In that I have got an application named "[DSP Manager](http://www.cyanogenmod.com/features/dsp-equalizer)" which can dramatically increase bass levels.

I thought it would be very nice if I could get something similar for my MacBook Pro.

Comment: You could always just use the built in iTunes equalizer found in the Window menu. Or do you need features outside of this?

Comment: @MikelR - I have tried it. But I would like features outside of it.

Comment: Since it's become obvious that @cloudlight doesn't want it just for iTunes, I've reworked the question to apply more generally.

Comment: @JasonSalaz - I was more concerned about iTunes. But its nice to have and know a system wide sound booster application.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[BOOM](http://www.globaldelight.com/boom/)!

It's a very simple app, costs just $9 [on the Mac App Store](http://itunes.apple.com/us/app/boom/id415312377?mt=12) as of this writing.

We covered this app on the Ask Different Podcast, [episode 15](http://apple.blogoverflow.com/2011/10/podcast-15-iphone-4s-an-ios-5-growl-remembering-steve-jobs/). [Nathan needed an app](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/26980/is-there-an-app-that-creates-a-system-wide-audio-equalizer) to apply a satisfactory EQ output to all system audio, as he's begun to use Spotify more often than iTunes, and Spotify does not have an EQ function built in.

Thus, we have BOOM! A variety of uses (gain/leveling, EQing, etc.), with a simple interface, and a low cost.

Comment: I would alsoo totally recommend Boom! It's a great app and does exactly the thing you want. Booming the volume or applying an overall EQ-panel of your Mac!

Comment: Boom is really great about compressing the sound enough, but not so much that it sounds awful from Mac speakers.

Answer (score 1):

I only know of [iWOW](http://www.srslabs.com/store/store/comersus_viewItem.asp?idProduct=18), which is pretty decent.

Comment: I tried this right now and It is pretty nice.

Answer (score 1):

[image]

I didn't want to pay to have an equalizer so I developed my own one and giving it away for free! Click [here](http://www.bitgapp.com/eqmac/) to download eqMac! The app is signed by Apple and works for OSX 10.9 and higher!

Answer (score 0):

[Hear](http://www.joesoft.com/products/hear.php) is one solution. It is commercial, but a time-restricted demo is available for free. It also works with other apps besides iTunes.